# Netsuite rest API for upsert is responding with 401 response code intermittently

Tags: node.js, oauth, netsuite, oauth-1.0a, netsuite-rest-api

I have code setup to make a call to Netsuite Rest API - (upsert using external id) in Node JS using token based authentication.
I can say that the code is working because the API returns 204 response code and netsuite record gets created through it. However, intermittently the API is returning 401 response code as well.
Almost half no. of times the API call returned 401 code.

Infact when tried the same payload in Postman (with which 401 response was returned from the above method), it worked and 204 was returned. I have no clue why it is working intermittently when run programmatically.

Also, not sure it matters but just for info, I am running the code in Cloud Functions (GCP).

**Code**:

```
function upsertOperation(externalId, body) {

  const baseUrl = `https://${NETSUITE_ACCOUNT_ID}.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/${RESOURCE}`;

  const oauthNonce = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
  const oauthTimestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  const oauthSignatureMethod = 'HMAC-SHA256';
  const oauthVersion = '1.0';
  const realm = `${REALM}` // Note: Replaced space with underscore and lower case letters with upper case letters in netsuite account id. Not provided exatct value here.

  const oauthParameters = {
    oauth_consumer_key: CONSUMER_KEY,
    oauth_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
    oauth_nonce: oauthNonce,
    oauth_timestamp: oauthTimestamp,
    oauth_signature_method: oauthSignatureMethod,
    oauth_version: '1.0'
  };

  const sortedParameters = Object.keys(oauthParameters)
    .sort()
    .map((key) => `${key}=${oauthParameters[key]}`)
    .join('&');

  const signatureBaseString = `PUT&${encodeURIComponent(baseUrl+'/eid:' + externalId)}&${encodeURIComponent(sortedParameters)}`;
  const signingKey = `${CONSUMER_SECRET}&${ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET}`;
  const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', signingKey);
  hmac.update(signatureBaseString);
  const oauthSignature = hmac.digest('base64');

  const headers = {
    'Prefer': 'transient',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `OAuth realm="${realm}",oauth_signature="${oauthSignature}",oauth_nonce="${oauthNonce}",oauth_signature_method="${oauthSignatureMethod}",oauth_consumer_key="${CONSUMER_KEY}",oauth_token="${ACCESS_TOKEN}",oauth_timestamp="${oauthTimestamp}",oauth_version="${oauthVersion}"`
  };

  fetch(baseUrl+'/eid:' + externalId, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    redirect: 'follow'
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error upsertOperation:', error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit***: The signature is generated correctly and base64 encoded as it should be.  However, the base64 character set includes `+`, `/`, and `=` which are not URL safe.  Therefor the signature must be URL encoded also - `encodeURIComponent(oauthSignature)` - before adding it to the Authorization header.

---

Here's a theory, for what it's worth...

From https://oauth.net/core/1.0/#nonce

> Unless otherwise specified by the Service Provider, the timestamp is expressed in the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT. The timestamp value MUST be a positive integer and MUST be equal or greater than the timestamp used in previous requests.

***IF*** you are making the request from two systems with different times, eg: GCP Cloud Functions and your own computer through Postman, ***then*** you could have a scenario where some requests are made with an earlier timestamp than a previous request, which will be rejected according to Oauth specification.

If there are no requests coming from a different system, it could be that the system you are using has a different time from NetSuite's server.  I have seen this be a problem previously ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74199773/7885772)), but not sure if that could cause an *intermittent* issue.  I guess it could if the timestamp to system time comparison included rounding, and the difference between the system times is close to the rounding cut-off point.

One other possibility is that GCP is running two instances of this practically simultaneously, or within a very short time.  One instance starts, another starts with a later timestamp, but makes the http call first.  In that case the first triggered request could be rejected because of its earlier timestamp.

Comment: Requests are made from only one system here. I checked the logs based on your answer. For a request which was successful with 204, the oauth timestamp passed was 1695087344. The immediate request after it had the oauth timestamp 1695087347 and it failed with 401. Even the nonce was unique for each. So, requests are failing even with newer timestamps.

Comment: Is your system's clock in sync with NetSuite?

Comment: Requests are coming to cloud functions through a webhook. And almost half of the requests have succeeded with 204 and nearly the same count has failed with 401. This makes me think that timezone may not be the issue here otherwise all would have failed.

Comment: Could you check the Login Audit Trail, making sure the Details column is added to the search, and advise what the Details field has for the failed logins?

Comment: Ok. I checked for the failed logins, the Details field says InvalidSignature. Not sure what it means. The same code (present in the question above) was used to generate the signature for the successful ones as well.

Comment: That just confirms it's the signature generation causing the error - see https://<accountid>.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=subsect_156935170194.html .  So, not much help beyond what we already know/assume.  I noticed in all the examples that the oauth_signature is at the end of the authorization header.  Clutching at straws, but you could try that.

Comment: Intermittent errors are the worst.  I guess the question is: what changes between the calls that succeed and the ones that fail?  The code is the same, but what about the input parameters?  EG: is there any correlation between the failures and the values in `${RESOURCE}`?  Also, have you submitted a case with NetSuite support in case there's a potential bug on their side?  That certainly wouldn't be unheard of...

Comment: I got it! For the requests which returned 401, the oauth signature had special characters. For the successful ones, the signature didn't had special characters. That's why it was intermittently not working as we cannot control which characters would the signature have. One more step was needed in the code to encode the final signature. After encoding the final signature using encodeURIComponent(oauthSignature), I am not seeing the 401 error now.

Comment: Thank you Krypton for narrowing down the area of concern which eventually helped me in finding the root cause! May be you can update the answer and I can accept it for anyone facing similar issue in future to refer.

Comment: Yaaayyy!  So simple and yet...  I looked at the encoding a bunch of times and thought 'yeah, he's got the base64 there, must be something else.  Always a lot easier once it's solved :)